# When potatoes are part of, say, Bacalao, why aren't they boiled into a mash?

Tags: potatoes

If I boil potatoes for an hour or more they invariably turn into a mash.

Why doesn't this happen if the potatoes are part of Bacalao that is left to simmer for a lot longer?

Comment: One possibility: Boiling potatoes subjects them to what amounts to violent action, which is bound to damage the potato. At a simmer, the potato is handled much more gently. Perhaps the difference is why a potato in bacalao lasts so much longer than one that is just boiled. Other possibility: I use potatoes in several soups, and my personal theory is that because potatoes absorb salt, it makes them more stable. They will cook down to mush eventually, but it takes a lot longer if there's salt involved. (Sorry about all the edits. It posted this comment every time I hit the Enter key.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do potatoes cook more slowly in a stew?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108074/why-do-potatoes-cook-more-slowly-in-a-stew)